# Header PHP to Text File - Remove Encoding

Tags: php, encoding, download, header

I have a php page that outputs text. I want to download this page into a text file. I am using:

```
  header('Content-type: application/txt');
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=savethis.txt");
```

This download the file just fine but the contents of the file is not correct. My text is a space/character seperated file so i have lines like this:

```
Data1     Data2             Data3
```

With a set number of spaces between each datapoint. When it downloads, instead of coming over like above, it is showing like

```
 Data1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Data2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Data3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Is there another header that I can set so that the spaces are not encoded to read "&nbsp"? I need the spaces there but not the html space character.

I cant seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - don't encode them. :-)

`&nbsp;` is the named HTML entity for the Unicode character `NO-BREAK SPACE` or `U+00A0`. So this is not a `SPACE` (U+0020). You have some code that explicitly adds them and/or encodes them to HTML entities. The best option would be to locate that logic in your source code an change it. Look for something that adds `&nbsp;` or calls like `htmlentites()`.

Your content type is strange (I would expect `text/plain`). From you description it seems that the browser renders your response as HTML. It decodes the entities and displays the content separated by no-break spaces. If you view the actual source of the response in the developer tools of your browser it should include the entities. Basically what happens is the same as rendering HTML tags.

It is possible to replace the entities. A simple way would be string replace:

```
$out = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $in);
```

A regular expression would allow to replace groups of entities:

```
$out = preg_replace('((&nbsp;)+)', ' ', $in);
```

However if the encoding was done using `htmlentities()` it might have encoded other characters as well. `html_entity_decode()` provides decode for named HTML entities, but the result would be no-break spaces. You might need to combine it with `str_replace()`:

```
$in = 'hello&nbsp;world&nbsp;&auml;hm';

$out = str_replace(
  "\u{00A0}", " ", html_entity_decode($in,  ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, 'utf-8')
);

var_dump($out);
```

Output:

```
string(16) "hello world ähm"
```

Comment: But be aware that this is not something PHP does automatically, your have some logic in the source that produces this result.